# Run playbook as a different user

Tags: ansible

I have added ssh keys of ansible user to other hosts so ansible user is allowed on all hosts.Now I want to run playbook as root or any other service users like apache etc. i have already indicated user as ansible in my playbook i got below mentioned errors when I run playbook while logged in as root. **But everything works fine when I run playbook while logging in as ansible user**.

```
- hosts: nameservers
  user: ansible
  tasks:
  - name: check hostname
  command: hostname
```

Error,

```
[root@dev playbooks]# ansible-playbook pingtest.yml

PLAY [nameservers] *********************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *****************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [x.x.x.x]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).", "unreachable": true}.
```

note: i have replaced IPs with x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setuser in playbook

```
user: ansible
```

set keypath in ansible configuration file

```
private_key_file = /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: still same issue i have added line in my /ansible/hosts file


([nameservers]
x.x.x.x  ansible_user=ansible)

Comment: try to use ssh command to validate that you can connect `ssh -i /path/to/sshkey  ansible@x.x.x.x `

Comment: i can not connect without entering the other host's password.

`ssh -i /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ansible@x.x.x.x`

Comment: no you must use the private key , it should be named based on your public key `id_rsa`  with ou th `.pub`extension

Comment: yes i am able to connect
`[root@dev playbooks]# ssh -i /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa ansible@x.x.x.x
Last login: Sat Aug  1 03:26:43 2020 from x.x.x.x
[ansible@host1 ~]$`

Comment: try setting  `private_key_file = /home/ansible/.ssh/id_rsa`    in ansible.cfg `[defaults]`  section .

Comment: Thanks working now.
set user ansible in playbook and defined key in ansible.cfg